# server busy popup in SAP GUI using Blue Prism

Tags: sap-gui, blueprism

I have automated one SAP GUI application, facing an unexpecting pop-up(server busy popup) issue. It is not occurring at a particular stage and whenever this popup occurs Blue Prism is stop working until someone click on (Switch to, Retry) that popup. Please help me with the solution how can I handle that exception

Comment: Unless you want to check for it after each action... maybe check the SAP settings? Maybe there's a 'checkbox' which disables it? Finally, afaik SAP is governed by the company's IT department. Try get in contact with them to find a workaround.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. We have checked with SAP they are saying that it should disappear after 8 seconds. But it is not happening.

Comment: I am not that technically strong. But I have an Idea.. Can we do anything with try, catch blocks here? please let me know whether it is possible ot not.. If yes, please give me an Idea.

Answer (score 0):

When you're automating SAP there are two possible modes used - either any of BluePrism ones (win32, region or active-accessibility), or a special, SAP mode.

When using a BluePrism automation mode, you have necessary tools at your disposal - you can use wait stages, sleeps to maneuver through your application and handle common situations that can happen like this pop-up.

When you're using a SAP Scripting mode, then actually you're using a language called SAP Scripting mode and it's a different story. You are connecting to SAP using SAP Object Model and executing a code. SAP mode has a lot of advantages - for example there is no need for wait stages and whenever you are executing a line of code, then the BluePrism will wait until SAP will say it has been finished.

The problem happens when there are pop-up windows that do not return "initiative" to the BluePrism. In situations like that BluePrism is waiting for SAP, and SAP is waiting for User and the process is dead locked.

You have few ways to fix that situation:

- You can build your own SAP-Utility object, that will connect to SAP using SAP scripting. Then you should be able to use Try - catch with timeout setting used.
- You can ask for change requests to your IT to stop this error from happening

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solutions!! We have contacted SAP IT team regarding the popup Issue, they replied that it will disappear after 8 seconds. but it is not happening in real time. I want to go for your first solution but the problem here is - popup is not occuring at particular stage. Can you please explain me in detail.. How can I execute SAP utility object in Blue prism when blueprism is waiting for SAP.

Comment: Hi, I am not C# or .net expert actually.. can anyone please help me in this issue..? how can I write try or catch blocks with timeout exception in code stage.